# Disobidient divs

Tags: css, html

I'm building a Homepage and am currently creating a banner with a linkbar under it. I want the banner and linkbar to be contained within a div called #content-top. The banner will be 1000px wide and 100px high while the linkbar under it is supposed to be the same width but 40px high. The banner will consist of two divs (each 500px wide and 100px high) and will both have backgroundimages. The linkbar will consist of a six divs each 16.6% wide.

This is the relevant code:

CSS:

```
        #content-top{
                     border: 1px solid #00FF00;
                     position: relative;
                     width: 1000px;
                     height: 140px;
                     }

                     #logotype-banner{
                             border: 1px solid #FF0000;
                             position: relative;
                             width: 500px;
                             height: 100px;
                             top: 0px;
                             left: 0px;
                             background-image: url(../images/logotype1.jpg);
                             background-repeat: no-repeat ;
                             }

                     #banner{
                             border: 1px solid #0000FF;
                             position: relative;
                             width: 500px;
                             height: 100px;
                             top: 0px;
                             left: 500px;
                             background-image: url(../images/banner1.gif);
                             background-image: repeat-x ;
                             }

                     #linkbar{
                             border: 1px solid #000000;
                             position: relative;
                             width: 1000px;
                             height: 40px;
                             top: 140px;
                             left: 0px;
                             }

                             #element-linkbar{
                                     position: relative;
                                     left: 0px;
                                     display:block;
                                     float: left;
                                     width: 16.66666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666%;
                                     height: 40px;
                                     background-image: url(../images/linkbar1.gif);
                                     background-image: repeat-x ;
                                     text-align: center;
                                     }
```

HTML:

```
                     <div id="content-top">

                             <div id="logotype-banner">

                             </div>

                             <div id="banner">

                             </div>

                             <div id="linkbar">

                                     <font size="-1">

                                     <div id="element-linkbar">
                                     <a href="#" style="display:block; height:100%; width:100%;"><br>#</a>
                                     </div>

                                     <div id="element-linkbar">
                                     <a href="#" style="display:block; height:100%; width:100%;"><br>#</a>
                                     </div>

                                     <div id="element-linkbar">
                                     <a href="#" style="display:block; height:100%; width:100%;"><br>#</a>
                                     </div>

                                     <div id="element-linkbar">
                                     <a href="#" style="display:block; height:100%; width:100%;"><br>#</a>
                                     </div>

                                     <div id="element-linkbar">
                                     <a href="#" style="display:block; height:100%; width:100%;"><br>#</a>
                                     </div>

                                     <div id="element-linkbar">
                                     <a href="#" style="display:block; height:100%; width:100%;"><br>#</a>
                                     </div>

                                     </font>

                             </div>

                     </div>
```

My problem is that two of the div boxes won't go where I want them to go, one won't have the correct 500px width and the background image won't show up in one of them.

This is how it currently looks (borders are added to see where the div boxes are):

Hoping for further help I will post my complete code here:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

```
     <head>

             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles_main.css"/>

             <meta name="norton-safeweb-site-verification" content="h60wcavnem8s78fz9cb-8opnk4-0gnbrj96984njpvzwfznwsibjtxcjygfcglwa7x9vz1m61p6ht9uathveehck7zyeyjz5abm5bqdwvpftsmuu-vqc2dz4r4koxxo9" />

             <script type="text/javascript">

                       var _gaq = _gaq || [];
                       _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36568939-1']);
                       _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

                       (function() {
                         var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                         ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                         var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                       })();

             </script>

                     <title>

                             #

                     </title>

     </head>

     <body>

             <div id="content">

                     <div id="content-top">

                             <div id="logotype-banner">

                             </div>

                             <div id="banner">

                             </div>

                             <div id="linkbar">

                                     <font size="-1">

                                     <div id="element-linkbar">
                                     <a href="#" style="display:block; height:100%; width:100%;">#</a>
                                     </div>

                                     <div id="element-linkbar">
                                     <a href="#" style="display:block; height:100%; width:100%;">#</a>
                                     </div>

                                     <div id="element-linkbar">
                                     <a href="#" style="display:block; height:100%; width:100%;">#</a>
                                     </div>

                                     <div id="element-linkbar">
                                     <a href="#" style="display:block; height:100%; width:100%;">#</a>
                                     </div>

                                     <div id="element-linkbar">
                                     <a href="#" style="display:block; height:100%; width:100%;">#</a>
                                     </div>

                                     <div id="element-linkbar">
                                     <a href="#" style="display:block; height:100%; width:100%;">#</a>
                                     </div>

                                     </font>

                             </div>

                     </div>

                     <div id="content-bot">

                             <div id="left-column">
                             </div>

                             <div id="center-column">
                             </div>

                             <div id="right-column">
                             </div>

                     </div>

             </div>

     </body>
```

CSS:

```
a:link {text-decoration: none; color:#FFFFFF;}
a:visited {text-decoration: none; color:#FFFFFF;}
a:hover {background-color: #8FF0F1; text-decoration: none; color: #000000;}
a:active {background-color: #8FF0F1; text-decoration: none; color: #000000;}

body{
     position: relative;
     background-color: #DADCDC;
     font-family:Verdana; Arial; sans-serif;
     font-size: small;
     font-color:#444444;
     min-width: 1200px;
     top: 0px;
     bottom: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     right: 0px;
     }

     #content{
             position: relative;
             background-color: #FFFFFF;
             width: 1000px;
             margin-left: auto;
             margin-right: auto;
             }

             #content-top{
                     position: relative;
                     width: 1000px;
                     height: 140px;
                     }

                     #logotype-banner{
                             position: relative;
                             float: left;
                             width: 500px;
                             height: 100px;
                             background-image: url(../images/logotype1.jpg);
                             background-repeat: no-repeat ;
                             }

                     #banner{
                             position: relative;
                             float: right;
                             width: 500px;
                             height: 100px;
                             background-image: url(../images/banner1.gif);
                             background-image: repeat-x ;
                             }

                     #linkbar{
                             position: relative;
                             clear: both;
                             width: 1000px;
                             height: 40px;
                             }

                             #element-linkbar{
                                     position: relative;
                                     left: 0px;
                                     display: block;
                                     float: left;
                                     width: 16.66666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666%;
                                     height: 40px;
                                     background-image: url(../images/linkbar1.gif);
                                     background-image: repeat-x ;
                                     text-align: center;
                                     line-height: 3;
                                     }


             #content-bot{
                     position: relative;
                     width: 1000px;
                     min-height: 1800px;
                     }

                             #left-column{
                                     position: relative;
                                     width: 200px;
                                     left: 0px;
                                     }

                                     #greybar-left-column{
                                             position: relative;
                                             width: 180px;
                                             height: 1px;
                                             top: 40px;
                                             left: 13px;
                                             background-image: url(../images/greypixel1.gif);
                                             background-image: repeat-x ;
                                             }

                             #center-column{
                                     position: relative;
                                     width: 600px;
                                     left: 200px;
                                     }

                                     #greybar-center-column{
                                             position: relative;
                                             width:
                                             height: 1px;
                                             top: 40px;
                                             left:
                                             right:
                                             background-image: url(../images/greypixel1.gif);
                                             background-image: repeat-x ;
                                             }

                             #right-column{
                                     position: relative;
                                     width: 200px;
                                     left: 800px;
                                     }

                                     #greybar-right-column{
                                             position: relative;
                                             width: 220px;
                                             height: 1px;
                                             top: 40px;
                                             right: 20px;
                                             background-image: url(../images/greypixel1.gif);
                                             background-image: repeat-x ;
                                             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT AFTER FULL CODE POST**

OK...here's what you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/Fb9E7/

You had some code in your HTML you didn't need (`font size`) and you need to stop using `left:px` to position `relative` elements. That works for `absolute` positioning - not `relative`.

Also, for your main `body` CSS styles, you had semicolons (;) instead of commas (,) after your fonts. That will stop some CSS styles from properly rendering as well.

Comment: Thanks for your respons but the weird thing is that even if I copy your code and remove mine instead of making changes to mine I still have the same problem. :(                                                      (Btw I just added the borders so that you could see where the divs were (my intention was to remove them later) but the problem is the same even if you remove them.)

Comment: Then you have something else in your code causing an issue as you can see by the fiddle it's working. Here's the fiddle updated without borders: http://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/Ec44f/1/

Comment: Might it have something to do with that #content-top is in the div                        #content{
                 position: relative;
                 background-color: #FFFFFF;
                 width: 1000px;
                 margin-left: auto;
                 margin-right: auto;
                 } which contains a second div                  #content-bot{
                         position: relative;
                         width: 1000px;
                         min-height: 1800px;
                         }? Thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: That should not matter. I'm assuming the `#content-bot` is your footer area. That shouldn't make a difference either. If my original answer helped, you should mark it as accepted, or post your full code for further help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Nothing noticeable happens.